C# pinned memory and balances on performance improvement
The question is about C# pinned memory and balances on performance improvement. In sample below,
'AllocateMemory' will allocate byte[] pinned in memory. You'd only do this ONCE. Pinned memory will not be garbage collected, reducing performance impact from GC.
'SerializeOrderBook' will use BitConverter.GetBytes and Buffer.BlockCopy to serialize 'originalOrderBook' to a byte[] pinned in memory.
'DeserializeOrderBook' will recovert from bytes[] pinned in memory, back to an OrderBook object.
'SerializeOrderBook' and 'DeserializeOrderBook' is called once during initial snapshot, but every updates -- Thus the question is, serialization + deserialization every updates will this negate the performance benefits (reduce GC loads) of pinning memory in the first place?
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Level
{
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public float Amount { get; set; }
    public int NumOrders { get; set; }
}

class OrderBookUpdate
{
    public string Symbol { get; }
    public List<Level> Bids { get; set; }
    public List<Level> Asks { get; set; }
    public long Timestamp { get; set; }
    public long PrevSeqId { get; set; }
    public long SeqId { get; set; }
    public long Checksum { get; set; }

    public OrderBookUpdate(string symbol)
    {
        Symbol = symbol;
    }

    public static OrderBookUpdate ParseUpdate(string symbol, dynamic messageObject)
    {
        OrderBookUpdate update = new OrderBookUpdate(symbol);

        update.Asks = ParseLevels(messageObject.data[0].asks);
        update.Bids = ParseLevels(messageObject.data[0].bids);
        update.Timestamp = messageObject.data[0].ts;
        update.PrevSeqId = messageObject.data[0].prevSeqId;
        update.SeqId = messageObject.data[0].seqId;
        update.Checksum = messageObject.data[0].checksum;

        return update;
    }

    private static List<Level> ParseLevels(dynamic levels)
    {
        List<Level> parsedLevels = new List<Level>();

        foreach (var level in levels)
        {
            parsedLevels.Add(new Level
            {
                Price = float.Parse(level[0].ToString()),
                Amount = float.Parse(level[1].ToString()),
                NumOrders = int.Parse(level[3].ToString())
            });
        }

        return parsedLevels;
    }
}

class OrderBook
{
    public string Symbol { get; }
    public long LastTimeStamp { get; set; } // For example, 1711941149203, 13 digits (i.e. in milli-sec)
    public List<Level> Bids { get; set; }
    public List<Level> Asks { get; set; }

    public OrderBook(string symbol, long lastTimestamp)
    {
        Symbol = symbol.Trim();
        LastTimeStamp = lastTimestamp;
        Bids = new List<Level>();
        Asks = new List<Level>();
    }

    public static OrderBook ParseSnapshot(string symbol, dynamic messageObject)
    {
        OrderBook orderBook = new OrderBook(symbol, Convert.ToInt64(messageObject.data[0].ts));

        foreach (var ask in messageObject.data[0].asks)
        {
            orderBook.Asks.Add(new Level
            {
                Price = float.Parse(ask[0].ToString()),
                Amount = float.Parse(ask[1].ToString()),
                NumOrders = int.Parse(ask[3].ToString())
            });
        }

        foreach (var bid in messageObject.data[0].bids)
        {
            orderBook.Bids.Add(new Level
            {
                Price = float.Parse(bid[0].ToString()),
                Amount = float.Parse(bid[1].ToString()),
                NumOrders = int.Parse(bid[3].ToString())
            });
        }

        return orderBook;
    }

    public float GetMidPrice()
    {
        if (Bids.Count > 0 && Asks.Count > 0)
        {
            float bestBid = Bids[0].Price;
            float bestAsk = Asks[0].Price;
            return (bestBid + bestAsk) / 2;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public void UpdateBook(OrderBookUpdate update)
    {
        UpdateLevels(Bids, update.Bids);
        UpdateLevels(Asks, update.Asks);
    }

    private void UpdateLevels(List<Level> currentLevels, List<Level> newLevels)
    {
        foreach (var newLevel in newLevels)
        {
            var existingLevel = currentLevels.Find(l => l.Price == newLevel.Price);
            if (existingLevel != null)
            {
                if (newLevel.Amount == 0)
                {
                    currentLevels.Remove(existingLevel);
                }
                else
                {
                    existingLevel.Amount = newLevel.Amount;
                    existingLevel.NumOrders = newLevel.NumOrders;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                currentLevels.Add(newLevel);
            }
        }

        currentLevels.Sort((a, b) => a.Price.CompareTo(b.Price));
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Log(string message)
    {
        string utcDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Console.WriteLine($"{utcDateTime} {message}");
    }

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string baseUrl = "wss://ws.okx.com:8443/ws/v5/public";
        string symbol = "BTC-USDT-SWAP";
        string subscribeBooksRequest = "{\"op\":\"subscribe\",\"args\":[{\"channel\":\"books\",\"instId\":\"" + symbol + "\"}]}";
        string subscribeBooks5Request = "{\"op\":\"subscribe\",\"args\":[{\"channel\":\"books5\",\"instId\":\"" + symbol + "\"}]}";

        using (ClientWebSocket clientWebSocket = new ClientWebSocket())
        {
            try
            {
                await clientWebSocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(baseUrl), CancellationToken.None);
                await SendMessage(clientWebSocket, subscribeBooksRequest);
                await ReceiveMessage(clientWebSocket);
                await SendMessage(clientWebSocket, subscribeBooks5Request);

                OrderBook orderBook = null;
                // You allocate byte[] pinned in memory only once.
                byte[] orderBookBuffer = AllocateMemory(symbol);

                while (clientWebSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
                {
                    string receivedMessage = await ReceiveMessage(clientWebSocket);

                    /*
                        SerializeOrderBook will use BitConverter.GetBytes and Buffer.BlockCopy to serialize 'originalOrderBook' to a byte[] pinned in memory.
                        DeserializeOrderBook will recovert from bytes[] pinned in memory, back to an OrderBook object.
                    */
                    unsafe
                    {    
                        dynamic messageObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(receivedMessage);
                        if (messageObject.action == "snapshot")
                        {
                            OrderBook originalOrderBook = OrderBook.ParseSnapshot(symbol, messageObject);
                            SerializeOrderBook(symbol, originalOrderBook, orderBookBuffer);
                            fixed (byte* ptr = orderBookBuffer)
                            {
                                orderBook = DeserializeOrderBook(symbol, ptr, orderBookBuffer.Length, originalOrderBook.Bids.Count, originalOrderBook.Asks.Count);
                            }
                        }
                        else if (messageObject.action == "update")
                        {
                            if (orderBook != null)
                            {
                                fixed (byte* ptr = orderBookBuffer)
                                {
                                    orderBook = DeserializeOrderBook(symbol, ptr, orderBookBuffer.Length, orderBook.Bids.Count, orderBook.Asks.Count);
                                }
                                OrderBookUpdate update = OrderBookUpdate.ParseUpdate(symbol, messageObject);
                                orderBook.LastTimeStamp = update.Timestamp;
                                orderBook.UpdateBook(update);
                                SerializeOrderBook(symbol, orderBook, orderBookBuffer);
                            }
                        }

                        if (orderBook != null)
                        {
                            Log($"{symbol} mid: {orderBook.GetMidPrice()}");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log($"An error occurred: {ex.Message} {ex.StackTrace}");
            }
        }
    }

    static async Task SendMessage(ClientWebSocket clientWebSocket, string message)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
        await clientWebSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(bytes), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
    }

    static async Task<string> ReceiveMessage(ClientWebSocket clientWebSocket)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        WebSocketReceiveResult result;
        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();

        do
        {
            result = await clientWebSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
            message.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, result.Count));
        }
        while (!result.EndOfMessage);

        return message.ToString();
    }

    static byte[] AllocateMemory(string symbol) {
        const int MAX_BID_COUNT = 1000;
        const int MAX_ASK_COUNT = 1000;
        int size = symbol.Length * 2 +                // String: 2 bytes per char
                sizeof(long) +                                  // LastTimeStamp (8 bytes)
                sizeof(float) * 3 * MAX_BID_COUNT +             // Bids: Price, Amount, NumOrders
                sizeof(float) * 3 * MAX_ASK_COUNT;              // Asks: Price, Amount, NumOrders
        byte[] pinnedMemory = new byte[size];
        return pinnedMemory;
    }
    static void SerializeOrderBook(string symbol, OrderBook orderBook, byte[] bytes)
    {
        int offset = 0;

        byte[] symbolBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(orderBook.Symbol);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(symbolBytes, 0, bytes, offset, symbolBytes.Length);
        offset += symbolBytes.Length;

        Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(orderBook.LastTimeStamp), 0, bytes, offset, sizeof(long));
        offset += sizeof(long);

        // Serialize Bids
        Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(orderBook.Bids.Count), 0, bytes, offset, sizeof(int));
        offset += sizeof(int);
        foreach (var bid in orderBook.Bids)
        {
            Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(bid.Price), 0, bytes, offset, sizeof(float));
            offset += sizeof(float);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(bid.Amount), 0, bytes, offset, sizeof(float));
            offset += sizeof(float);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(bid.NumOrders), 0, bytes, offset, sizeof(int));
            offset += sizeof(int);
        }

        // Serialize Asks
        Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(orderBook.Asks.Count), 0, bytes, offset, sizeof(int));
        offset += sizeof(int);
        foreach (var ask in orderBook.Asks)
        {
            Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(ask.Price), 0, bytes, offset, sizeof(float));
            offset += sizeof(float);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(ask.Amount), 0, bytes, offset, sizeof(float));
            offset += sizeof(float);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(ask.NumOrders), 0, bytes, offset, sizeof(int));
            offset += sizeof(int);
        }
    }

    static unsafe OrderBook DeserializeOrderBook(string symbol, byte* ptr, int length, int numBids, int numAsks)
    {
        int offset = symbol.Length;
        long timestamp = BitConverter.ToInt64(new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(ptr+offset, sizeof(long)));
        OrderBook orderBook = new OrderBook(symbol, timestamp);        
        offset += sizeof(long);

        for (int i = 0; i<numBids; i++)
        {
            float price = BitConverter.ToSingle(new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(ptr + offset, sizeof(float)));
            offset += sizeof(float);
            float amount = BitConverter.ToSingle(new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(ptr + offset, sizeof(float)));
            offset += sizeof(float);
            int numOrders = BitConverter.ToInt32(new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(ptr + offset, sizeof(int)));
            offset += sizeof(int);
            orderBook.Bids.Add(new Level { Price = price, Amount = amount, NumOrders = numOrders });
        }

        for (int i = 0; i<numAsks; i++)
        {
            float price = BitConverter.ToSingle(new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(ptr + offset, sizeof(float)));
            offset += sizeof(float);
            float amount = BitConverter.ToSingle(new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(ptr + offset, sizeof(float)));
            offset += sizeof(float);
            int numOrders = BitConverter.ToInt32(new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(ptr + offset, sizeof(int)));
            offset += sizeof(int);
            orderBook.Asks.Add(new Level { Price = price, Amount = amount, NumOrders = numOrders });
        }

        return orderBook;
    }
}


Allocating a buffer once and reusing it is a good idea to reduce GC pressure. I'm not sure about "negating" part, this is a standalone performance improvement.
More perf tips based on the attached code:

Consider ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent for this purpose
Use pooled buffer in ReceiveMessage instead of allocating arrays
Prefer Span<byte> over pointers, it does not require pinning and is safer
Avoid dynamic. For maximum performance try source-generated JSON serialization.
Consider SortedDictionary for currentLevels.


I meant, having to serialize+deserialize every updates: Will this hurt the performance more than the benefits we get from pinning the memory?
